# Swift / delivery method name to IBAction to create dependency

Tags: ios, swift

In my example I have 3 buttons. Two of the buttons with the same responsibility level and the 3rd button has a dependency on the first ones. I want the 3rd button to call the method of either Button 1 or Button 2, depending on if Button 1 or Button 2 has been pressed.

```
exampleMenu.buttnOne.addTarget(self, action: #selector(ViewController.firstBtnFunc(_:)), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
exampleMenu.buttnTwo.addTarget(self, action: #selector(ViewController.secondBtnFunc(_:)), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
```

I was thinking of something like this to solve my needs:

```
var currentButton:String = ""

func buttnOne(button: UIButton) {
    currentButton = "buttnOne"
}

func buttnTwo(button: UIButton) {
    currentButton = "buttnTwo"
}

@IBAction func thirdButtonAction(sender: AnyObject) {

    if currentButton == "buttnOne" {
        buttnOne()
    } else if currentButton == "buttnTwo" {
        buttnTwo()
    }
}
```

But that way I get the error: `Missing argument for parameter #1 in call`

Using `ViewController.buttnOne()` gives me the error: `Use of instance member buttnOne on type ViewController; did you mean to use a value of type ViewController instead?`

How can I solve my issue? Help is very appreciated.

Edit as requested:

[image]

Don't mind the interface at the moment. It's in beta and not finished yet. But it gives the idea. 
I want the user to chose a category. Like liquids. And a sub-category like ML (mililiters).

The ML button has the following code:

```
    func mlBtnFunc(button: UIButton!) {
    var numberInt:Double = Double(numberStr)!

    tableData = ["Mililiter", "Centiliter", "Liter", "Ounces", "Cups", "Gallons"]
    tableCounterData = ["\(numberInt) ml", "\(numberInt * 0.1) cl", "\(numberInt * 0.01) l", "\(numberInt * 0.0338135) oz", "\(numberInt * 0.00422676) cups", "\(numberInt * 0.000264172) gallons"]
    print(numberStr)

    currentButton = "mlBtnFunc"
}
```

Now I want the "go" button in the keyboard section to call the function again to recalculate the value the user has entered. To make that happen, I call it now like that:

```
    @IBAction func enterKeyboardAction(sender: AnyObject) {

    if currentButton == "mlBtnFunc" {
        mlBtnFunc(nil)
    } else if currentButton == "clBtnFunc" {
        clBtnFunc(nil)
    }

}
```

You really can't call this best practice, but I don't know how to tell the `enterKeyboardAction` what values have to calculated... Any advice would is appreciated. But at the moment the app does, what I want her to do.

Comment: I would suggest factoring out the calculation from the button. Since both ML button and Go button need to recalculate, you could have a function `recalculate` which they _both_ call. `recalculate` could look at what the current button is, and do the right recalculation for that button. So ML button's code would just be `currentButton = "mlBtnFunc"; recalculate()`, and `enterKeyboardAction` code would just be `recalculate()`. At first, `recalculate` would be a big `switch` statement, depending on the `currentButton`, though I can think of ways to refine it further...

Comment: that is actually a good idea with the factoring. esp since i have 20 values to calculate... thank you for your time and advice

Comment: Just to clarify: What I'm trying to do is prevent you from mixing interface (view) with data (model). Your code says "pretend the user tapped the ML button again." That feels wrong because it isn't what happened; the user tapped the Go button. So what I'm saying is, if the ML button and the Go button do the same thing, make that a _thing_ that they _both_ do, independently — rather than pretending that one button is the other button.

Comment: yes. i can see that and I'm really thankful for that argument. i will try to transpose that. thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `buttnOne` and `buttnTwo` methods require a UIButton parameter, but you are not supplying it when you call them. If they sometimes do receive a `button` parameter and sometimes don't, you can declare them with an Optional UIButton parameter and call them with `nil`, like this:

```
func buttnOne(button: UIButton!) {
    currentButton = "buttnOne"
}

func buttnTwo(button: UIButton!) {
    currentButton = "buttnTwo"
}

@IBAction func thirdButtonAction(sender: AnyObject) {

    if currentButton == "buttnOne" {
        buttnOne(nil)
    } else if currentButton == "buttnTwo" {
        buttnTwo(nil)
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you. that did it. i can't upvote anymore today. (limit reached) i will by tomorrow morning. in 4 mins i will check as solved. thank you!

Comment: But that's just a stopgap; your entire proposed architecture is extremely dubious.

Comment: If I understood better what the real point was, I'd propose an entirely revised architecture.

Comment: I can provide a little more code of the actual project. If you're interested in giving me an advice... I'm sure that I'm not working with best practice... But I just thought it might be a way to do what I want.... I'll edit my question. Need like 3-4 mins for that.